# Can't send embeds to certain discord channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send an embed message to a specified channel in the method below. However, the embed message doesn't send when I put it in by itself or with anything else. However, sending strings worked fine.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def report(ctx, user, reason):
    if ctx.channel.id == 730496513255669881:
            channel = bot.get_channel(730432681657237594)
            embedstaff = discord.Embed(title="A new player report has been submitted!", color=0xff6a00)
            embedstaff.add_field(name="Player/User Reported", value=ctx.author.name, inline=True)
            embedstaff.add_field(name="Reporter", value="Lol", inline=True)
            embedstaff.add_field(name="Report Reason: " + reason, value="", inline=False)
            await channel.send("Heyy x3", embed = embedstaff)
```

Is there an alternative way to send a message to a specified channel? Or is there a solution to the method I am using now?
(How mention a role would be nice too haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mention a role by using role.mention once you get the `Role` Object. You can fetch the role using `get` from `discord.utils`

```
from discord.utils import get
#inside a command
role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='role')
await ctx.send(f'Hello {role.mention}')
```

Fetching a channel by Id and sending an embed to that channel is the standard method. That said `Guild` has attributes such as `system_channel, afk_channel, rules_channel`. So if any of those are set you could simply get them from `ctx`

```
rules = ctx.guild.rules_channel
```

Answering the title, you could check whether the channel you're sending the embed to has embeds enabled or not.

Comment: What do you mean by using the `ctx.guild.rules_channel` object? Does this only specify a channel named "rules-channel"? For the channel have embed links enabled do you mean permissions wise for the bot or something else?

Comment: If you have a system channel set in Server settings you can get the channel from `ctx.guild` I've not used `rules_channnel` before and yes permissions for the bot.